# How to split path and file names from multiple items from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a list below

```
list = ['C:/Users/user/Desktop/1.docx', 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/2.docx', 
'C:/Users/user/Desktop/3.docx']
```

I want to split path and file names from the list like this:

```
pathlist = ['C:/Users/user/Desktop/'], and filelist = ['1.docx', '2.docx', '3.docx']
```

Any help and suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `rsplit` your list by the delimiter `"/"`, and then `append` the parts to your path and file lists:

```
pathlist = []
filelist = []

for item in list:
     pathlist.append(item.rsplit("/",1)[0])
     filelist.append(item.rsplit("/",1)[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
pathlist = list(set(os.path.dirname(name) for name in list))
filelist = list(set(os.path.basename(name) for name in list))
```

Comment: @ Matt Shin. Its splitting the path and filenames, but also its shuffling the file names.